# java: cannot access org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject - class file for org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject not found

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, apache-poi

I have converted a normal Intellij java project into a maven project. After this I found the right dependencies for my program I am writing. I am getting the following message for
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTTable;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTTableStyleInfo;
Can anyone help?
[IntelliJ error message prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0WNf.png)

Here are also my maven dependencies:
[Maven dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov5SY.png)

Comment: can you provide your maven dependencies? these classes are in poi-ooxml-lite which is a transitive dependency of poi-ooxml

Comment: looking at your image - the error to be that you are missing xmlbeans 5.0.2 from your classpath - this is a transitive dependency of poi-ooxml-lite